# GUI Branch Strategy w/ Submodules

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

I have a repo "**repo1**" with 2 branches "*main*" and "*dev*" with 3 submodules "**submodule1**", "**submodule2**" and "**submodule3**".

All 3 submodules can only be tested together in "**repo1**".

If i develop a feature in "**submodule1**", i create a branch from "*main*" in "**submodule1**".

When the feature from "**submodule1**" is ready to be tested, i want to checkout "*dev*" in "**repo1**", update all submodules (with something like "git update submodule") in their "*dev*" branches.

After testing "*dev*" in "**repo1**", i want to merge all "*dev*" from all submodules to their "*main*".

Then i want to checkout "*main*" in "**repo1**" and update all submodules in their "main" branches, so i can push it and have a working branch in "*main*" from "**repo1**" that i can pull in other machines.

I know, that i can do "git update submodule submodule1" after adding "branch = main" in .gitmodules, but how can i do it for "*dev*" and "main" without having to change it every time? Is there a way to do it or is there a better method for it?

What i want is basicaly to check out all submodules to "*dev*" in "**repo1**", test them, switch to every submodule and merge their "*dev*" into "*main*", then check out all submodules to "*main*" in "**repo1**" and push it.